# How to convert a datareader to datatable

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-2.0

I have a question about converting a `datareader` to a `datatable`.  In my code, I have a `datareader` created in one class and passed to another class that I want to convert it to a `datatable`.

When I do this, it does not seem to work, as the table remains empty. If I do the conversion in the same function, it works fine.

Its only when I pass the `datareader` to another function that it **stops working**.  Is this because the `dr` is closed or something?  How do I overcome this problem?  Any help would be great.

Comment: You should never pass `DataReader`'s as you will completely miss to dispose the objects or several times the data will not be there anymore. Can you edit the method that is in use, the one before returning the `DataReader`? So for example you can add a `DataTable` property to that method and populate it prior to the return so you can grab outside that `class`...

Comment: no, i was instructed to only return a datareader.  the logic being that the function that passes the datareader can be used elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```
Public Function ExecuteQuery(ByVal s As String, ByVal condb As SqlConnection, ByVal ParamArray params() As SqlParameter) As DataTable
        Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
        Using da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(s, condb)               
            dt = New DataTable
            If params.Length > 0 Then
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(params)
            End If
            If da.SelectCommand.Connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then da.SelectCommand.Connection.Open()
            da.Fill(dt)                    
        End Using
        Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  is there anyway to do this without knowing the connection or parameters?  The only thing that I'm passed is the datareader.  thanks

Comment: ParamArray is optional so you dont need to pass any parameter :), please mark my anser as Right

Answer (score 55):

Use DataTable `Load()` method.

```
 // Given a DataReader called "reader"
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Load(reader)
```

Comment: Does `reader.Read()` need to be called before? If there are multiple rows in the reader, are they all copied to the DataTable?

Comment: You do not need to call Read before. It is probably best if you don't. My guess is you will miss the first record if you do.